# Delete a quote in PHP

Tags: php

In my Excel file I have a parameter that contains a description (type String) of an Article.
In the parsing file, it does not read a field of a Description that contains a `quote '`; it jumps over them, like with this example of a description:

```
CABO VERDE 'TACV'
```

I changed a getter method by adding a test, but it doesn't work:

```
public function getName() {
  if($this->_name= str_replace(''','\'', $this->_name)){       
    return $this->_name;
  }
}
```

How can I change the method to read all the data of a description field?

Comment: you forgot a `\ ` in the first string of the `str_replace` and I don't understan exactly what you want to do

Comment: What is the `if()` statement for? What are you trying to test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Comparison operator is `==`, not `=`

2) Syntax is incorrect; Either escape inner quotes, or use double quotes

It should be

```
if($this->_name==str_replace("'",'', $this->_name)
```

This code is trying to find out if there is an ' in the string, there are many ways of doing that. I would have used

```
if(strstr($this->_name,"'")===FALSE)
// ' is not present in name
```

But your method is not wrong either.

Comment: It might be that OP simply wants to test if `$this->_name` is non-empty after replacing the quotes and reassigning it to `$this->_name`. Then the single `=` would make sense. Example field value: `''`; this would fail the condition. Otherwise it's hard to figure out what the `if()` statement is trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, technically possible but I'm inclined more towards thinking that its a malformed comparison. If it was supposed to work with an `=` that way then any name that is not empty will be approved, regardless of whether it has an `'` or not.  OP's indication that they want to avoid names with `'` counters that possibility imo

Comment: True, but then I don't understand what the `if` condition is trying to achieve. OP stated they want to read all data of a field if it contains a quote, but the `if` statement will do the opposite. I've asked OP for clarification. Perhaps OP can elaborate. However, since your answers is accepted, I guess OP's problem is solved. :-)

Comment: @DecentDabbler It's a little confusing way of checking but it does serve the purpose. That if condition is will return false if a string contains `'` and hence a name will not be returned. If the OP had put an else clause it would have made more sense

Answer (score 1):

Using your current str_replace method:

```
if($this->_name == str_replace("'", "", $this->_name)
{
   return $this->_name;
}
```

While it's hard to see, the first argument is a double quote followed by a single quote followed by a double quote. The second argument is two double quotes with nothing in between.

With str_replace, you could even have an array of strings you want to remove entirely:

```
$remove[] = "'";
$remove[] = '"';
$remove[] = "-"; // just as another example

$FileName = str_replace( $remove, "", $this->_name);
```